# npm run does not work as expected on a docker container

Tags: node.js, docker, npm, scripting

I'm building a react app with vite and I'm deploying it with docker.

When deploying the container, `npm run build` runs but does nothing, even doing it inside the container manually won't work.

I get this output but the actual build does not happen:

```
$ npm run build

> frontend@0.0.0 build
> tsc && vite build

$
```

Thing is if I run `tsc && vite build` it works just fine.

Same goes with `npm run dev` or any other script.

Here's more info:

- Tried with both Node Alpine and Debian (I'm actively developing in Alpine).
- Tried creating the Node user and setting permissions accordingly since I read that `npm` might behave weird if ran by the root user.
- ```
  $ npm config get ignore-scripts
  false
  ```

These are my docker files

```
FROM node:20-bullseye
WORKDIR /app/frontend/
COPY package.json package-lock.json* /app/frontend/
RUN npm install
RUN npm install -g vite
RUN npm install -g typescript

COPY . .
RUN chown -R node:node /app/frontend/

USER node

CMD ["npm", "run", "build"]
```

docker-compose.yaml:

```
version: "3.4"
name: fisy-prod
services:
  backend:
    volumes:
      - static:/static
    env_file:
      - ./.env
    build:
      context: ./backend
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.prod
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
  frontend:
    build:
      context: ./frontend
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.prod
    volumes:
      - frontend:/app/frontend/dist
  nginx:
    build:
      context: ./nginx
    volumes:
      - static:/static
      - frontend:/var/www/frontend
    ports:
      - "5173:80"
    depends_on:
      - backend
      - frontend
volumes:
  static:
  frontend:
```

I scouted the web all morning without really finding anything that might point to the issue. Would appreciate it if someone that has experienced this could help.

Comment: You seem to be showing interactive shell commands, but you wouldn't usually use those in Docker.  What is in your Dockerfile?  How are you running the container?

Comment: @DavidMaze In this case I grew tired of rebuilding and rebuilding so at one point I started to mess around with the docker terminal. 
Sorry I didn't post those before, I edited my post with the Dockerfile and the docker-compose.yaml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Compose file has `volumes:` blocks that replace all of the image content with content from named volumes.  This apparently works the first time you run the container, since Docker copies content from the image into an *empty* volume; but if you rebuild your application, the volume will not get updated, and the old content in the volume will replace your image content.

One important part of this problem is that your `frontend` container doesn't really do anything.  Its `CMD` is to *build* the application, but that will immediately exit.  This doesn't need to be a long-running container and it doesn't need to be listed in your Compose file.

What I'd do here is to use a *multi-stage build* to compile the frontend, then `COPY` all of the content into an Nginx-based image.  For example:

```bash
FROM node:20-bullseye AS frontend
WORKDIR /app/frontend/
# Note, run with the project root as the build context
COPY frontend/package.json frontend/package-lock.json ./
...
RUN npm run build

FROM nginx:1.25
COPY nginx/default.conf.tmpl /etc/nginx/default.conf.tmpl
COPY backend/static/ /static/
COPY --from=frontend /app/frontend/dist/ /var/www/frontend/
```

Now the final image contains all of the pieces you need, so you don't need to try to share files between containers; that means you can remove all of the `volumes:`.  The final image build also encapsulates the front-end build, so you don't need a separate `frontend` build-only container.  This leaves you with a Compose file

```yaml
version: "3.8"
services:
  backend:
    env_file:
      - ./.env
    build:
      context: ./backend
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.prod
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
  nginx:
    build:
      context: .  # needed to COPY files from subdirectories
      dockerfile: nginx/Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "5173:80"
    depends_on:
      - backend
```